# Append object existing file

Tags: java

I would like to append Serializable objects in a existing file, but apparently it deletes the previous stored objects.

For the parameter **File F**, I send *new File(file's path)*. Maybe my mistake is from there ?

Thank you for helping.

```
public static void wrinting(File[] tab, File f) throws Exception{

    ArrayList<ImageClass> obj = imagesArray(tab); 
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));    
        for (ImageClass i : obj) {
           oos.writeObject(i);
        }
        oos.close();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `FileOutputStream` like this instead:

```java
new FileOutputStream(f, true)
```